# React - Passing data to Grand parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

As above structures , I would like to pass some states to "Left Components" which is Grand-Grand-Grand parent components.

```
 var grandChildRight = React.createClass({
      clicksomething : function () {
         this.setState({data:'you clicked me'});
      }
});

var leftComponent : React.createClass({
     render : function () {
         {this.props.data}
     };
 });

HTML 
<div class="left">
 <leftComponent data="?" />
</div>
<div class="right">
<rightComponent>
   <anotherComponent>
        <grandChildRight />
    </anotherComponent>
</rightCompoent>
</div>
```

Is any way I can do this without using "Flux" or "Redux".
Please help me out this.

Thanks lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding container that wraps your HTML and adding a callback prop to `grandChildRight` for it to call when its state updates:

```
var grandChildRight = React.createClass({
    clicksomething: function () {
        this.props.onUpdate({data:'you clicked me'});
    }
});

var leftComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        {this.props.data}
    };
});

var container = React.createClass({
    onRightGrandChildUpdate: function( newState ) {
       this.setState(newState);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div className="container">
          <div className="left">
             <leftComponent data={this.state.data} />
          </div>
          <div className="right">
            <rightComponent>
              <anotherComponent>
                <grandChildRight onUpdate={this.onRightGrandChildUpdate.bind(this)} />
              </anotherComponent>
            </rightCompoent>
          </div>
        </div>);
    }
});
```

(Notice the `.bind(this)` when passing `this.onRightGrandChildUpdate` to `onUpdate` of the `grandChildRight` component. Doing so ensures `this` binds to the container component, and not the current global object.)

Then your "HTML" becomes:

```
<container />
```

Essentially, this lifts the `data` you're interested in to a level above both the right grandchild and left component. The supplied `onUpdate` property allows the right grandchild to update the container's state, which then affects the `data` passed into the left component.

Comment: I am having following issue : 

warning.js:44 Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See Container

Comment: My bad , I should do with  *.bind(null,this)

Comment: Nope, you definitely don't want `.bind(null, this)`! That will ensure the first argument to your callback will always be the `<Container />` component, rather than the data you want to pass. I haven't run into that warning in React recently, but if it says you're good to remove `.bind(...)` I would trust it.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a Parent Component above all of this then GrandChildRight Component will let Parent Component about any change then Parent Component will tell Left Component about the change

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
     handleEventChange : function(event){
         this.setState({data:event.data})
     },
     render : function () {
         <LeftComponent data={this.state.data}/>
         <RightComponent onEventChange={this.handleEventChange}/>

     };
});

var LeftComponent = React.createClass({
     render : function () {
         <div>{this.props.data}</div>
     };
});

var RightComponent = React.createClass({
     render : function () {
         <GrandChildRightComponent onChildChange={this.handleChildEvent}/>
     };
     handleChildEvent : function (event) {
         this.props.onEventChange({data: event.data})
     };

});

var GrandChildRightComponent = React.createClass({
      clicksomething : function () {
         this.props.onChildChange({data:'Grand child is clicked'})
      }
});
```